# Parallel Azure CloudBlockBlob-operations crashing (access violation)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The code sample below results once in a while in an access violation (1 out of 5,000 to 10,000 messages). Using a serial `foreach` instead of `Parallel.ForEach` seems to circumvent the problem.

```
public void DequeBatch<T>(int count)
{
    var messages = this.queueListen.ReceiveBatch(count);
    var received = new ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>>();

    Action<BrokeredMessage> UnwrapMessage = message =>
        {
            blobName = message.GetBody<string>();
            obj = Download<T>(blobName);

            received.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid, T>(new Guid(blobName), obj));
        };

    // offending operation
    Parallel.ForEach(messages, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = count }, UnwrapMessage);
}

public override T Download<T>(string blobName)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob;
    lock (this.containerDownloadLock)
    {
        blob = this.containerDownload.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    }

    T result;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        result = Decompress<T>(stream);         // dehydrate an object of type T from a GZipStream
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Q1**: What is the offending part which makes the code above thread-*unsafe*?

**Q2**: What is the correct and safe approach to up- and download `CloudBlockBlob`s in parallel?

**Edit**

Today, the code outlined above ran into a dead-lock. After hitting break-all in the debugger I observed that all of the worker-threads executing `blob.DownloadToStream(stream);` were trapped in

[`System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.EnterLock`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.cs)

except for one which was blocked (no exception or anything else) in

[`System.Net.WinHttpProxyFinder.WinHttpGetProxyForUrl`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WinHttpWebProxyFinder.cs)

Comment: What is the call stack at the exception?

Comment: @S.T. Unfortunately, the call stack does not show any code at all for most of the threads.

Comment: What does it show? Specifically for the thread that threw an exception?

Comment: @S.T. The exact exception is `System.AccessViolationException` in unknown module. No code shown.

Answer (score 1):

An exception `System.AccessViolationException` can only originate from unmanaged code or from unsafe managed code. What you have above is normal (i.e. safe) managed code, so you should not be scrutinizing that code at the moment, but instead focus on other possibilities:

1. Do you have any unmanaged or unsafe code in your app? If so, that might be a reason for memory corruption, which in turn would cause an Access Violation. [Test your app under paged heap and GFlags](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx).
2. Execute your app under debugger and collect a crash dump. Look at the crash dump and check if you have familiar code in the call stack. A Windgb's `!analyze` command would get the analysis for you automatically. You will have to have to know how to fix up symbols for your and 3-rd party libraries. Example is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anandbms/archive/2005/04/20/410225.aspx).
3. It might be a bug in Microsoft's implementation of Blob.

If you reasonably excluded #1 and #2, and suspect #3 might be the issue, you should collect a crash dump and send it over to Microsoft, only they would be able to help in that case.